# How do I copy folder server to server with phpseclib?

Tags: php, backup, sftp, phpseclib

I want to create backup data from server to server using library phpseclib. This is my script:

```
<?php
include "lib/Crypt/RSA.php";
include "lib/Crypt/Base.php";
include "lib/Crypt/RC4.php";
include "lib/Crypt/AES.php";
include "lib/Net/SFTP.php";
include "lib/Math/BigInteger.php";

set_include_path('lib/'); 

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('172.1.xxx.xx');
if (!$sftp->login('root', 'xxxx')) {
    exit('login failed');
}

$sftp->chdir('/opt/oss/server/var/fileint/fm');
$files = $sftp->nlist('.', true);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
        continue;
    }
    $dir = './Alarm/' . dirname($file);
    if (!file_exists($dir)) {
        //mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($dir . '/' . $file, $sftp->get($file));
}
```

but it still errors

> PHP WARNING : file_put_contents ( )

Answer (score 3):

Building off of your script:

```
<?php
set_include_path('lib/'); 

include "lib/Net/SFTP.php";

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('172.1.xxx.xx'); // source server
if (!$sftp->login('root', 'xxxx')) {
    exit('login failed');
}

$sftp2 = new Net_SFTP('172.1.xxx.xx'); // destination server
if (!$sftp2->login('root', 'xxxx')) {
    exit('login failed');
}

$sftp->chdir('/opt/oss/server/var/fileint/fm');
$files = $sftp->nlist('.', true);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
        continue;
    }
    $dir = './Alarm/' . dirname($file);
    if (!$sftp2->file_exists($dir)) {
        $sftp2->mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
    }
    $sftp2->put($dir . '/' . basename($file), $sftp->get($file));
}
```

This will copy a directory from one remote server to another remote server. Note that if you want to copy a directory from a remote server to another *directory* on that same server then I would just reuse the `$sftp` object instead of creating a new `$sftp2` object. But it doesn't *seem* like that's what you're asking.