# Can you SFTP a directory to a remote server with phpseclib library

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

Does anyone know if you can move directories from a local environment to a remote environment with sftp phpseclib library.

I have this:
$ssh->put('/logs/file6.text', 'bfiles/file.text', SFTP::SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE);

But this makes a new file (file6.text) in remote environment and stashes the content of local file (file.text) in it.

I need to just copy a directory over. I have zipped files in a directory and just need to transfer them.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/55143490/569976 do what you want? That code is for phpseclib 1.0, mind you. I can port it to phpseclib 2 or 3 if you want.

Comment: The short answer is: "No, there is not built in recursive copy or wildcarding." The medium answer is: "Yes, but you have to implement it all yourself. Eg: loop over the files yourself, create directories, check if the remote file exists, handle cases arising from those, etc." The long answer is basically what neubert linked.

Comment: I haven’t tried this specific combination, but the PHP League’s Flysystem supports [SFTP](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/adapter/sftp-v3/) which uses phpseclib under the hood and has some [higher level file system abstractions](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/usage/filesystem-api/)